# CaGEL equivalent to obligatory adverbial?

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases, complements, syntactic-analysis

When I learnt grammar in school, I was taught that there are optional and obligatory adverbials. Trying to understand grammar in the form presented by Huddleston and Pullum (e.g. *the Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* and *A Student's Introduction to English Grammar*), I'm wondering how to deal with "obligatory adverbials" such as the following:

(1) He is **in the garden**.

(2) He was **on his way**.

(3) He went **there**.

(4) His birthday is **today**.

If I'm not completely mistaken, the PPs in (1) and (2) would simply be called PP complements, but what about the phrases in (3) and (4)? Are they too PP complements, in line with the rather drastic re-analysis the authors suggest for adverbs/prepositions/subordinators?

Comment: They are not adjuncts (your 'adverbials') but locative/temporal  complements. That they are complements is evident from the fact that they are obligatory elements. Obligatory items are always complements -- they are required to complete the verb phrase. Optional elements may be complements or adjuncts.

Comment: @BillJ Thank you! So, is _locative complement_ the actual name of the function (in the same way as we have _direct object_, _predicative complement_ etc), or is it rather a term used to describe the semantic nature of these particular complements? I've found that H&P use the term _PP complement_ to quite some extent, so I was wondering whether that would be the term to use, in analogy with _direct object_ etc... Also, I'm wondering about (4): are you saying that's locative too? Because it's locative in time?

Comment: Locative and predicative are subtypes of complement, as are direct objects, but we generally use the function label "direct object" for the latter. I used the term 'locative' for (4) because it expresses temporal location. I've amended my comment for greater clarity.

Comment: @BillJ Yes, that's exactly what I meant – I wanted to know what subkind of complement we're dealing with here. I think I've got it now :) Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct about (1) and (2)—[CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521431468) would say they are locative complements in the form of a PP.

You are also correct about (3). CGEL does explicitly say that *there* is a preposition on p. 640, in the context of discussing prepositions whose complement is another PP:

> The PPs *here, there, now, then* occur as complement to a wider range of prepositions than do such PPs as *under the bed* or *after six*. We find, for example, *They live **near here**; Put it **on there**; I found it **behind here**; You should have told me **before now**; He certainly stayed **past then**.*

However, CGEL says (p. 429) that *today* is not a preposition, but a *deictic temporal pronoun*:

> *Yesterday, today, tonight,* and *tomorrow* are not traditionally analysed as pronouns, but belong in this subclass of nouns by virtue of their inability to take determiners. Compare, for example, *Today/*The today is my birthday.* They are also semantically like the central pronouns *I* and *you* in that they are characteristically used deictically. Unlike the temporal prepositions *now* and *then*, the pronouns have genitive forms: *today's*, etc.

As far as whether *locative* in *locative complement* is a syntactic or semantic characterization, CGEL seems to claim the former. On p. 257, in the section 'Relation between locative complements and predicative complements':

> We will not assimilate the locatives to the predicatives, but will regard them as syntactically distinct kinds of complement that exhibit certain semantic resemblances.

Comment: Thank you so, so much!! And thank you for integrating my question about _locative_ as well!! This answer is really helpful :) Just one more thing though: whereas I get the discussion of _today_, I wonder whether the analysis would be different in an example such as _They arrived today_, because it really doesn't make much sense saying _today_ is a NP in that case, does it? So in that case, would it be an AdvP or a PP, I wonder...

Comment: @Hannah: I think it has the same syntax as "They arrived the day that I left". Such sentences have an NP that appears to function like an adverbial or PP. Apparently some have suggested that there is a "covert" preposition in such constructions, if I understand the following Linguistics SE post correctly: [How common, crosslinguistically speaking, are 'bare NP' temporal adverbials?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/20988/how-common-crosslinguistically-speaking-are-bare-np-temporal-adverbials)

Comment: @Hannah In "They arrived today", "today" is an adjunct of temporal location realised by an NP with a deictic pronoun as head.

Comment: @Hannah I agree with what sumelic and BillJ said. One objection may be this: consider *They arrived [the day that I left]/[Monday]/[today]*. Now add *on* after *arrived*, and suddenly the *today* version becomes unacceptable. And if *today* were a pro-word that can stand for the other two, shouldn't it be able to function in the same way as the other two?

Comment: @Hannah I don't have a perfect reply, but I will note that if *Monday* is replaced by *this Monday*, then the addition of *on* starts feeling a bit odd to my ear: *?They arrived on this Monday*. Certainly the version with *on* is less common on google books. If I am correct about this decrease in naturalness, it shows that the acceptability of *on* in such constructions does depend on *which* temporal NP is supposed to be its complement, so it's not that far fetched that some temporal NPs cannot appear there at all.

Comment: @sumelic Thoughts about the above?

Comment: I think that different temporal nouns select different prepositions, apparently just as an arbitrary lexical specification (e.g. "on" is OK for "on this day" but not for * "on this year") so it doesn't seem too problematic that "on" might not be possible with "today", since even though that word is etymologically related to *day* it doesn't seem to synchronically be headed by the word *day.* So basically I think that I agree with you (I'm not sure about the contrast between "on Monday" and "on this Monday").

Comment: Regarding "if today were a pro-word that can stand for the other two", I think that might be what CGEL is getting at with "They are also semantically like the central pronouns I and you in that they are characteristically used deictically". Although "today" may be a pronoun, it seems to be not really the kind of pronoun that can be used to replace any specific other NP of the same type.

Comment: @sumelic True. Somehow I would still feel better if I could think of a construction that becomes even a little bit less acceptable if, say, *John* is replaced by *I* (ignoring the corrections for case and number that are peculiar to personal pronouns, of course: we may need to use *me*, or we may need to remove the *s* from some verb). In particular, I can think of no preposition that would accept *John* but reject *me*. But I agree that in the end, this difference between personal and deictic temporal pronouns is not a reason to doubt the pronoun identity of the later.